# Color bar for smoothScatter in R

Tags: r, 2d, histogram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R legend for color density scatterplot produced using smoothScatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271584/r-legend-for-color-density-scatterplot-produced-using-smoothscatter)

I am plotting a 2D histogram using smoothScatter in R. However I am unable to plot a legend that shows the scale (color to point density). Is there a way to make such a plot, or, better, a different plotting function that can generate it automatically?

What I currently have:

```
smoothScatter(x,y,colramp = customColors, pch="",nbin=499);
```

and what I'd like is a nice bar to the right with my `customColors` and more importantly the depth of the deepest "nbin".

Comment: You could use the code in `filled.contour` or simply use `stat_density2d` from the ggplot2 package.