# R legend for color density scatterplot produced using smoothScatter

Tags: r

I am producing a color density scatterplot in R using the `smoothScatter()` function.

Example:

```
## A largish data set
n <- 10000
x1  <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol = 2)
x2  <- matrix(rnorm(n, mean = 3, sd = 1.5), ncol = 2)
x   <- rbind(x1, x2)
oldpar <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
smoothScatter(x, nrpoints = 0)
```

Output:

[image]

The issue I am having is that I am unsure how to add a legend/color scale that describes the relative difference in numeric terms between different shades.  For example, there is no way to tell whether the darkest blue in the figure above is 2 times, 10 times or 100 times as dense as the lightest blue without some sort of legend or color scale.  Is there any way in R to retrieve the requisite information to make such a scale, or anything built in that can produce a color scale of this nature automatically?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899096/color-bar-for-smoothscatter-in-r#comment11130419_8899096)

Comment: @mnel I might resort to one of those approaches if need be, though ideally I'm after a way to do it using `smoothScatter()`.

Comment: Your solution will (probably) involve using the `postPlotHook` argument. You could look at the `fields::image.plot` function for how they create a legend.

Comment: I don't get it. The question @mnel linked to involved `smoothscatter`.

Comment: @Dwin the comment mnel linked to does not though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an answer that relies on `fields::imageplot` and some fiddling with `par(mar)`  to get the margins correct

```
fudgeit <- function(){
  xm <- get('xm', envir = parent.frame(1))
  ym <- get('ym', envir = parent.frame(1))
  z  <- get('dens', envir = parent.frame(1))
  colramp <- get('colramp', parent.frame(1))
  fields::image.plot(xm,ym,z, col = colramp(256), legend.only = T, add =F)
}

par(mar = c(5,4,4,5) + .1)
smoothScatter(x, nrpoints = 0, postPlotHook = fudgeit)
```

[image]

You can fiddle around with image.plot to get what you want and look at `?bkde2D` and the `transformation` argument to `smoothScatter` to get an idea of what the colours represent.

Comment: Question: What does the 0.5 in the bar scale indicate?

Comment: Okay. Now, I know the value is the number of 'z' in the function of fudgeit. but what's z indicate.

Comment: I second the question. What do the numbers on the scale mean?

Comment: Doing some digging on the y scale: it is the `dens` value from the [.smoothScatterCalcDensity](https://github.com/cran/lattice/blob/master/R/panel.smoothscatter.R) function, which is assigned to be `fhat` term of [the bkde2D result](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/KernSmooth/versions/2.23-15/topics/bkde2D), "*a matrix of density estimates over the mesh induced by x1 and x2*".